# Get total (count) per month in Power BI

Tags: count, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, measure

I have an 'issue' data set in `CSV` format that looks like this.

```
Date,IssueId,Type,Location
2019/11/02,I001,A,Canada
2019/11/02,I002,A,USA
2019/11/11,I003,A,Mexico
2019/11/11,I004,A,Japan
2019/11/17,I005,B,USA
2019/11/20,I006,C,USA
2019/11/26,I007,B,Japan
2019/11/26,I008,A,Japan
2019/12/01,I009,C,USA
2019/12/05,I010,C,USA
2019/12/05,I011,C,Mexico
2019/12/13,I012,B,Mexico
2019/12/13,I013,B,USA
2019/12/21,I014,C,USA
2019/12/25,I015,B,Japan
2019/12/25,I016,A,USA
2019/12/26,I017,A,Mexico
2019/12/28,I018,A,Canada
2019/12/29,I019,B,USA
2019/12/29,I020,A,USA
2020/01/03,I021,C,Japan
2020/01/03,I022,C,Mexico
2020/01/14,I023,A,Japan
2020/01/15,I024,B,USA
2020/01/16,I025,B,Mexico
2020/01/16,I026,C,Japan
2020/01/16,I027,B,Japan
2020/01/21,I028,C,Canada
2020/01/23,I029,A,USA
2020/01/31,I030,B,Mexico
2020/02/02,I031,B,USA
2020/02/02,I032,C,Japan
2020/02/06,I033,C,USA
2020/02/08,I034,C,Japan
2020/02/15,I035,C,USA
2020/02/19,I036,A,USA
2020/02/20,I037,A,Mexico
2020/02/22,I038,A,Mexico
2020/02/22,I039,A,Canada
2020/02/28,I040,B,USA
2020/02/29,I041,B,USA
2020/03/02,I042,A,Mexico
2020/03/03,I043,B,Mexico
2020/03/08,I044,C,USA
2020/03/08,I045,C,Canada
2020/03/11,I046,A,USA
2020/03/12,I047,B,USA
2020/03/12,I048,B,Japan
2020/03/12,I049,C,Japan
2020/03/13,I050,A,USA
2020/03/13,I051,B,Japan
2020/03/13,I052,A,USA
```

I'm interested in analyzing the count of issues, particularly across months and years. Now if I wanted to simply plot a chart of issues by date, that's pretty easy. But what if I want to calculate total issues per month and plot it, and perhaps do some analysis of trends etc? How would I go about calculating these sums per (say) month to analyze.

The best approach I could take so far is the following.
I create a new column, called `YearMonth` which looks like this:

```
YearMonth = FORMAT(Issues[Date],"YYYY/MM")
```

Then if I plot `Axis = YearMonth` vs `Values = Count of IssueId`, I get what I want.

[image]

But the biggest drawback here is that my X-axis is the newly created column, not the original `Date` column. Since my project has other data that I would like to analyze using the date as well, I would like for this to be using the actual `Date` instead of my custom column.

Is there a way for me to get this same result but without having to create a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you usually do is [create a calendar table](https://www.aaronjgrossman.com/2018/03/25/dax-calendar-scripts/), which will contain all the time-related columns (year, month, year-month, etc) and then link it to your data by date.

In your visuals, you will then use the "Calendar" table columns, without having to alter your original table. The calendar table will be sued also by any other table that needs date related data.